# Prove that $\frac{a}{(1+b)(1+c)}+\frac{b}{(1+a)(1+c)}+\frac{c}{(1+a)(1+b)} \geq \frac{3}{4}.$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers that satisfy $abc = 1$, prove that $$\dfrac{a}{(1+b)(1+c)}+\dfrac{b}{(1+a)(1+c)}+\dfrac{c}{(1+a)(1+b)} \geq \dfrac{3}{4}.$$

**Attempt**

I tried doing $$\dfrac{a}{(1+b)(1+c)}+\dfrac{b}{(1+a)(1+c)}+\dfrac{c}{(1+a)(1+b)}  =  \dfrac{1}{bc(1+b)(1+c)}+\dfrac{1}{ac(1+a)(1+c)}+\dfrac{c}{bc(1+a)(1+b)}$$ then using the fact that $a^2+b^2+c^2 \geq ab+bc+ca$ but that only seemed to get me $$\dfrac{a}{(1+b)(1+c)}+\dfrac{b}{(1+a)(1+c)}+\dfrac{c}{(1+a)(1+b)} \geq \dfrac{1}{bc+bc^2+c+1}+\dfrac{1}{ac+a^2c+c+1}+\dfrac{1}{ab+ab^2+b+1}.$$

Comment: Use Cauchy inequality. Just sum it and use Cauchy.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$4(a(1+a)+b(1+b)+c(1+c))\ge 3(1+a)(1+b)(1+c).\tag{1}$$
Since 
$$(1+a)(1+b)(1+c) = 1+ (a+b+c)+(ab+bc+ca)+abc$$
and $abc=1$, Inequality (1) is equivalent to
$$4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c) \ge 6+3(ab+bc+ca).$$
The last inequality follows from $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ca$ and AM-GM.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part?

Comment: You beat me to it I suppose...

Comment: Why is $4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c) \ge 6+3(ab+bc+ca)$?

Comment: $4(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c) \ge 3(ab+bc+ca)+(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)\ge 3(abc)^\frac13+3(abc)^\frac23=6+3(ab+bc+ca)$ by AM–GM

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't follow.

Comment: @JacobWillis $$\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}=1$$
$$\frac{a+b+c}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{abc}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's sum it:
$$\frac{(a+1)a+b(b+1)+c(c+1)}{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)}$$, called it $(1)$

Now use Cauchy inequality:
$$(1) >= \frac{3((a+1)ab(b+1)c(c+1))^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)}$$, now

Derived all, what we can derive :)

And use Cauchy for $a+1,b+1,c+1$.

So continue it!

*Hint*: show that:
$$((a+1)(b+1)(c+1))^{\frac{2}{3}} >= 4$$

Comment: I posted it from my phone, so it's hard to write full solution.

Comment: Your inequality got flipped at some point.

Comment: @QuangHoang are you talking about $>=$ in forth line ?

Comment: Your 2nd inequality is $(1)>3 \left( (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\right)^{\color{red}-2/3}$. The RHS of which is *less* than $1/4$.

Comment: @QuangHoang yep

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Multiply both sides by $(1+a)(1+b)(1+c)$, and expand the aforementioned expression as follows: $1+abc+a+b+c+ab+ac+bc$.

You'll notice that you can substitute the value $1$ for $abc$; I think you should be able to tackle it from here by application of RM-AM-GM-HM inequality (Only AM-GM necessary though).